# LDAP error : Cannot find a partition

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

Am using Apache Directory Studio to build LDAP with Spring Security application.

LDIF file:

```
version: 1

dn: o=mojo
objectClass: organization
objectClass: top
o: mojo

dn: ou=users,o=mojo
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: users

dn: ou=groups,o=mojo
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: groups

dn: cn=Ramesh Kotha,ou=users,o=mojo
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
cn: Ramesh Kotha
sn: Kotha
uid: ramesh
userPassword:: cmFtZXNo

dn: cn=USER,ou=groups,o=mojo
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: USER
uniqueMember: cn=Ramesh Kotha,ou=users,o=mojo

dn: cn=ADMIN,ou=groups,o=mojo
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: ADMIN
uniqueMember: cn=Ramesh Kotha,ou=users,o=mojo
```

And my Test class is :

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DistinguishedName;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.ldap.filter.EqualsFilter;

public class LdapTest {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("LdapTest");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LdapContextSource ctxSrc = new LdapContextSource();
        ctxSrc.setUrl("ldap://localhost:10389/o=mojo");
        ctxSrc.setBase("o=mojo");
        ctxSrc.setUserDn("uid=admin,ou=system");
        ctxSrc.setPassword("secret");

        ctxSrc.afterPropertiesSet(); 

        LdapTemplate tmpl = new LdapTemplate(ctxSrc);

        PersonDao dao = new PersonDao(tmpl);
        dao.getAllPersonNames();

    }

    public static class PersonDao {

        private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

        public PersonDao(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate) {
            this.ldapTemplate = ldapTemplate;
        }

        public void setLdapTemplate(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate) {
            this.ldapTemplate = ldapTemplate;
        }

        public List getAllPersonNames() throws Exception {
            logger.info("getAllPersonNames called : ");
            EqualsFilter filter = new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "person");
            return ldapTemplate.search(DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH,
                    filter.encode(),
                    new AttributesMapper() {

                        public Object mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs) throws NamingException {
                            return attrs.get("cn").get();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for     SearchRequest
        baseDn : '2.5.4.10=mojo/o=mojo'
        filter : '(2.5.4.0=person)'
        scope : whole subtree
        typesOnly : false
        Size Limit : no limit
        Time Limit : no limit
        Deref Aliases : deref Always
        attributes : 
:  Cannot find a partition for 2.5.4.10=mojo/o=mojo]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for     SearchRequest
        baseDn : '2.5.4.10=mojo/o=mojo'
        filter : '(2.5.4.0=person)'
        scope : whole subtree
        typesOnly : false
        Size Limit : no limit
        Time Limit : no limit
        Deref Aliases : deref Always
        attributes : 
:  Cannot find a partition for 2.5.4.10=mojo/o=mojo]; remaining name '/'
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:174)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:306)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:237)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:588)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:546)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:421)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:441)
    at com.onlineexam.util.LdapTest$PersonDao.getAllPersonNames(LdapTest.java:49)
    at com.onlineexam.util.LdapTest.main(LdapTest.java:30)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for     SearchRequest
        baseDn : '2.5.4.10=mojo/o=mojo'
        filter : '(2.5.4.0=person)'
        scope : whole subtree
        typesOnly : false
        Size Limit : no limit
        Time Limit : no limit
        Deref Aliases : deref Always
        attributes : 
:  Cannot find a partition for 2.5.4.10=mojo/o=mojo]; remaining name '/'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3030)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2951)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2758)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1812)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1735)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:368)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:338)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:257)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate$3.executeSearch(LdapTemplate.java:231)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:293)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed the URL to `ctxSrc.setUrl("ldap://localhost:10389");` it is working fine.